# java missing required source folder: 'gen'

Tags: android, sdk

I just reformatted my computer. I have windows xp sp3 32 bit.
I install java jdk
android sdk
eclipse ide

When I go to make a new android project i get this error.

Project 'HelloAndroid2' is missing required source folder: 'gen'

Please help i'm new to eclipse so give detail responses.

Comment: did you install the adt plugin for eclipse?

Comment: Same problem here, nothing is fixing it.  I tried deleting folders, recreating them, refreshing the project, reopening Eclipse.  Nothing...

Comment: @CherylSimon Google's first result is now this thread.

Comment: @Cheryl this IS now the number 1 result on google . ppl like you need to chill out . you ruin the community by putting in more effort nit picking than helpinmg

Answer (score 98):

I just got this problem when I was trying to import a project that was originally created with a version of the SDK that is no longer installed on my machine.

Right click the project. Select Properties. Go to Android. Select a Project Build Target. Click Ok. You might have to clean and rebuild the project as well.

Comment: This fixed my problem. It was Facebook's SDK and it is targeted for Android 2.2, which I didnt have downloaded, so I downloaded the missing Android SDK version and it worked.

Comment: great idea! in my case it fix it!

Comment: Thank you! Solved the problem for me too.

Answer (score 10):

Right-click on the "gen" folder in Eclipse and select Properties. Then, remove the "Derived" checkbox. Then clean the project.

Comment: The ironies of Eclipse being what they are, **adding** this option fixed the problem for me.  Then the project still built after I removed the option and Cleaned everything.

Answer (score 7):

Most likely, there is a problem with one of your resources, preventing `R.java` from being generated in the `gen/` folder. You should have error messages in your Console related to this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Delete the "gen" folder. Then clean the project. Then build the project again. In my case it worked.

Answer (score 3):

try this...
Right click on the project in eclips
Android tools -> Fix project properties
its works for me

Comment: Worked for me, when I did @Gal's fix first.

Answer (score 1):

ok , here's what worked for me:

delete the project and **make sure you are not deleting it from the disk!**

import it again and it will solve the problem.

Good luck....

Comment: Worked for me, but after re-importing it I also applied @Mohammed's solution

Comment: This worked for me. I'm using eclipse 4.5 and trying to load a project created by an older version of eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

My case was: I imported Zhou Weikan's cocos2d-android and the error emerged. The most straight-forward solution that came to my mind was to create the folder (right-click on the project in Package Explorer -> New -> Folder and then create new folder named 'gen'. It worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

delete the gen and its content and clean the project again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to project
2. Right Click
3. New Folder  (**Res**)

In my case it works Fine

Answer (score 0):

I tried all these things and none of them worked.  One day all my projects are running, next day all my projects have an empty gen folder?

After a series of tests to resolve the phantom missing R.java, the one that led me to a drastic action is when I looked at the Properties > Android and the Project Build Target was greyed out and the project wasn't linked to any SDK, almost as if there were no SDKs installed. This was after I uninstalled 4.2 and reinstalled all tools and SDKs...

Long story short, after trying everything I could find online, I just deleted the whole "adt-bundle-mac-x86_64" folder in my workspace folder, unzipped the original download, and dragged the original folder back into the workspace.

This works as a last resort, however you will have to import all of your projects back into the package explorer by New > Project... > Android Project from Existing Code, and make sure you have the "Copy projects into workspace" UNCHECKED.

IMPORTANT: You will find that you can't do this if your "MainActivity" file is always named "MainActivity," so just for future project creating, it's good practice to always name your main activity something different each time.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred when I tried to graphically add a grid layout.  Deleting the grid layout folder fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to install android sdk build tools with Android SDK Manager.
The probkem was that whenever I clean the project, the gen directory becomes empty.

Hope it will help!

Answer (score 0):

if gen folder or R.java file is not generated then first check error in XML file and make sure android menifest.xml is present.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project> Properties>  Android > use the latest API
takes care of everything!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solution was downgrading the target from android-22 to android-19 at project.properties